# dynamic colors in the html :root

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, gulp

I need to have a page with dynamic colors that come from the database. in a sass file I have the styles in variables

```css
$color-primary: #56b4d8;

$theme-colors: (primary: $color-primary,
secondary: #56b4d8,
success: #0ebd65,
info: #198ae3,
warning: #fed713,
danger: #e64b4b,
light: #f8f9fa,
dark: #1a1a1a);
```

the primary color that is applied to the boostrap classes (text-primary, bg-primary, btn-primary) I want the sass $ color-primary variable to be filled with my data from DB

I am using asp.net core html, sass and gulp. This is possible

Comment: You will probably need to upgrade to Bootstrap 5.0 which utilizes CSS variables for its themes. Previous versions require the LESS/SASS code to be compiled which cannot be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add **asp.net** the question's tags because this is where the main problem lies.

You can not send dynamic variables to Sass but there may be an ASP.NET extensions that generates a Sass file.

Remember that Sass files cannot be read directly in a web page, they have to be compiled to standard CSS first and that's exactly what Gulp is doing